# Only groupby a key and not performing any other changes

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

Is it possible to just group rows by key without performing any changes to any other column than the key column going to index ?
If yes, how is can we do it ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            'id': ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
            'data1': [11,35,46,11,26,25,39,50,55],
            'data2': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],      
         })
df
```

I want a frame where we have `['A', 'B', 'C']` as index and every rows for data1 and data2 stored into index A if `id=A`, index B if `id=B` and index C if `id=C`

something like this :

```
   data1  data2
A   11      1
    35      1
    46      1
B   11      1
    26      1
C   25      2
    39      2
    50      2
    55      2
```

Comment: add examples of input and output

Comment: I know how to make the input example but I don't know how to make the output from `pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: its just at least schematics.. so if you can't produce a sample output you could just do a screenshot of excel with fake desired output

Comment: Ok got this output tip for next time, didn't think about it in first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not set `id` as index? Like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            'id': ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
            'data1': [11,35,46,11,26,25,39,50,55],
            'data2': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],      
         })

df.set_index(['id'], inplace=True)
df[df.index.isin(['A'])]
```

Output 1:

[image]

---

Alternatively could create a fake multi index?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
            'id': ['A','A','A','B','B','C','C','C','C'],
            'data1': [11,35,46,11,26,25,39,50,55],
            'data2': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],      
         })

### create empty column
df['empty'] = ''

### create multi index
df.set_index(['id','empty'], inplace=True)
```

[image]

```
# rename index to none if you dont want index name
df.index.set_names(None, level=0, inplace=True)
```

[image]

```
### query like this
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'A']
```

[image]

```
## or like this
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(0) == 'A'].droplevel(1)
```

[image]

Comment: yes it would be more someting like that. I think both answers are equivalent but this one add the step I needed to get what I want.

Comment: yes functionality wise both are the same in the end the latter just has an extra dummy index to make it look like your desired output

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you can iterate over result of `DataFrame.groupby()`:

```py
for idx, g in df.groupby("id"):
    print("Idx =", idx)
    print(g)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Idx = A
  id  data1  data2
0  A     11      1
1  A     35      1
2  A     46      1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Idx = B
  id  data1  data2
3  B     11      1
4  B     26      1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Idx = C
  id  data1  data2
5  C     25      2
6  C     39      2
7  C     50      2
8  C     55      2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Something like this yes, I putted a "written" example of output. The only difference would be that A, B or C would not be duplicated and be the index for respectively 3, 2 and 4 rows. I still was looking for other stuff and found that maybe this could be a `Multiindex` dataframe ?

Comment: @Lemisourd Maybe try `g.set_index("id")` ?

Comment: i'll try that, maybe it's enough to do what I want in next step of my code.